# Store JSON object in DynamoDB using Rust?

Tags: rust

I have just read in a JSON object, and now I would like to store it into DynamoDB as a structured data object.

In Python, this is easy:

```
data = {
    "id": str(time.time()),
    "metadata": {
        "author": "Me",
        "version": "0.7.1"
    },
    "values": [1.2235253, 1.4235235]
}
dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb", region_name="eu-west-2")
table = dynamodb.Table("MyTable")
cleaned_data = json.loads(json.dumps(data), parse_float=Decimal)
table.put_item(Item=cleaned_data)
```

In Rust... this is my code, but it errors:

```
use rusoto_core::Region;
use rusoto_dynamodb::{AttributeValue, DynamoDb, DynamoDbClient, PutItemInput};
use serde_json::{json, Value}; 

// JSON file to hashmap
let contents = fs::read_to_string("tests/fixtures/event.json").expect("Unable to read file");
let data: HashMap<String, Value> = serde_json::from_str(contents).unwrap();
write_to_dynamodb(data).await;

// Hashmap to DynamoDB
async fn write_to_dynamodb(data: HashMap<String, Value>) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let client = DynamoDbClient::new(Region::EuWest2);
    client.put_item(PutItemInput{
      item: data,
      table_name: "MyTable".to_string(),
      ..PutItemInput::default()
    }).await?;

    Ok(())
}
```

I get the following error on the `item: data` line:

```
item: data
      ^^^^ expected struct `AttributeValue`, found enum `Value`
note: expected struct `HashMap<_, AttributeValue>`
          found struct `HashMap<_, Value>`
```

It looks like DynamoDB expects a different data structure from the one offered by `serde_json`. Should I use something like `serde_dynamo`, and if so how?

NB I don't know the structure of my JSON object in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used [`serde_dynamodb`](https://crates.io/crates/serde_dynamodb), but it seems it provides the functions:

- `from_hashmap` - Deserialize an instance of type `T` from an `HashMap<String, AttributeValue>`.
- `to_hashmap` - Serialize the given data structure as an `HashMap<String, AttributeValue>`.

In your example you've used `HashMap<String, serde_json::Value>`, but that seems unnecessary. You could directly deserialize a JSON string into a `serde_json::Value`.

You should be able to directly convert `serde_json::Value` values into `HashMap<String, AttributeValue>` values via [`to_hashmap()`](https://vleue.com/serde_dynamodb/serde_dynamodb/fn.to_hashmap.html).

Both [`serde_dynamodb`](https://crates.io/crates/serde_dynamodb) and [`serde_json`](https://crates.io/crates/serde_json) are based on the [`serde`](https://crates.io/crates/serde) framework. They can be seen as Serde extensions for DynamoDB and JSON respectively, so you should be able to easily convert between the structures those two provide (both `Value` and `AttributeValue` implement Serde's `Serialize` and `Deserialize` traits).